# What constitutes a 'waxy potato'

Tags: vegetables, potatoes

Potato salad, dauphinoise, sauteed, with potato cooked but firm and keeping its form with a wonderful waxy texture. Common all over France but a rarity in the UK.

What varieties should we be looking for and where to find them?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, potatoes that are colored (red, gold, blue) tend to be waxier than white potatoes (red being the waxiest), and fingerling potatoes are the waxier than other sizes. A more complete list can be found [here](http://www.thekitchn.com/potato-varieties-64061).

Comment: Also, boiling your potato without peeling it first helps maintain waxiness.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Charlotte or Desiree potatoes at [Waitrose](https://www.waitrose.com/home/recipes/food_glossary/potatoes.html) in the UK, both of which are waxy and will hold their structure well when cooked.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to choosing younger, colored potatoes, your cooking method can have an effect.

The pH of the water they are boiled in can change their texture - adding vinegar helps keep them firm, baking soda for mashing.

This affects all types of potatoes, so a bit of vinegar will help regardless of variety.